# unable to install forexconnect python package

Tags: python, pip

I have python 3.9.6.

`Pip install, python3 pip install` none of these is able to install forexconnect(https://github.com/gehtsoft/forex-connect) package

```
$ python3 -m pip install  forexconnect
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement forexconnect (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for forexconnect
```

The error is the same on mac and linux (ubuntu). Please can I get help?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there aren't any [files on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/forexconnect/#files) for `forexconnect` for Python versions above 3.7, except for a single wheel for 3.10 on macOS/ARM64. A look at their [website](http://www.fxcodebase.com/wiki/index.php/Category:ForexConnect) confirms that. Since this appears to be a proprietary project which doesn't publish its source code, I don't think there's much you can do other than contact the company and complain, or just use Python 3.7.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  I found the same posting on their board, please have a look at:

https://fxcodebase.com/code/viewtopic.php?f=51&t=73024

basically it involves downloading an earlier whl and renaming it

Comment: Thank you Chris. Will give this a go and let you know